# Fatal error: require_once() : Failed opening required error with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have an application that works on my local, development server, but when uploaded to the remote, production server I see the following error:

```
   Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/madhab/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/madhab/public_html/system/database/DB.php on line 140
```

What's the matter? How can I resolve it?

//my database configuration as

```
$active_group = 'server'; 
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['server']['hostname'] = 'madhab-acharya.com.np';
$db['server']['username'] = '***********';
$db['server']['password'] = '***********';
$db['server']['database'] = '***********';
$db['server']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['server']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['server']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['server']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['server']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['server']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['server']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['server']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['server']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['server']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['server']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

//and my index.php file setting is

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
$assets_folder = 'assets';
```

while my application, system, index.php resides on public_html folder in remote server
somebody please help me thro this

Comment: The problem could also be of the file permissions. Just check the file permission in case.

Comment: i didnt get that sorry rabindra can you tell me in more details... im new in codeigniter

Comment: In your ftp, just right click your system folder and see file permissions assigned to folder and assign it 755 permissions to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with mysql host.
normally it is like `madhab-acharya.mysqlserver.com.np`. I think you have give your web site name.
Please check your sql hostiname with your web service provide or you can find it in phpadmin panel.

If this is correct ensure that every file is uploaded correctly. Sometimes I had to do second time when I put site in productions.

Comment: can you please tell me where can i find that mysqlserver, mysql hostiname in php my admin... is it- Server: **Localhost** via UNIX socket or something else.

Comment: go to your production site controlle panel, where you can find database creating option. Under the database you have to navigate to your relevent database . There you can find php amdin for database operations. If it is difficult try with customer care. they will give it to you

Comment: I am not talking about Localhost but production site web host

Comment: i give up.. :{ anyways  thanx menuka.. and i am looking that in production site.. i ran a sql query:- select @@hostname;
show variables where Variable_name like '%host%'; and find a host.. i did it but nothing work at all

Comment: I checked host using above command in a one of my production site. but it was differnce but I didnt check whther it works. However, you can easily done this If you contact your site administrator. If you are web is php , therre are lot of free website that gives facility to host php web sites. If you try one of them, you can get some background knoweledge of web hosting. one site I recomend is lazbit  site.

Comment: thanks menuka for your wonderful advice.. yeah i did it. with my new domain and host its up and runing.  http://ebazzar.co.nf  :) with some php errors.. may be i need your help next time